# EACCES (Permission denied) Android

Tags: android, compression, image-compression, file-access

**GOAL**: To perform compression on `image/content`, retrieved through external sources (ex: sd-card, internal or drive) using intent.

I was able to get actual path for the retrieved content, but when i am trying to compress it using compression library (**zetbaitsu/Compressor**) its throwing error

> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).

I have cross checked my permissions and tried multiple way to confirm permission access, still its throwing error.

**Here is my function:**

```
void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Uri imageUri =  intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSendImage: " + imageUri.toString());
        File imageFile = new File(getFilePath(this, imageUri));
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSendImage: " + Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        File compressedFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(imageFile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSendImage: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Here are my logs outputs:**

```
handleSendImage: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A30

handleSendImage: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/4c568534307d605ed94878dc06d933ee.jpg

handleSendImage: /storage/emulated/0/Download/4c568534307d605ed94878dc06d933ee.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  Add this permission in manifest application tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Add this in Manifest file but this won't work in android 11

Comment: do you know how to solve this issue when targeting Android 11? I faced this issue in Android 11, I was thinking to ask the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if user face the exception, but it need some works, moreover pass google review @bhaskar-pasupula